# Deleting hardlink with rm -rfv deletes the original?

Tags: linux, rm, hard-link

I was reading up on similar questions on here about what happens when you delete a hardlink to a file and the majority of the answers I was getting were that the hardlink is deleted but the original stays. However during my testing, if I have

`FileA.txt` and `LinkFileA.txt` both in separate directories, if I `rm -rfv` the directory that contains `LinkFileA.txt`, it **also** goes and deletes the original. Example:

`home/testing/dira/FileA.txt`
`home/testing/dirb/LinkFileA.txt`

`rm -rfv home/testing/dirb/*` deletes both the file in `dirb` **and** the file in `dira`.

Why is this?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of the `rm -rfv`? I'm rather surprised by the behaviour you're seeing...

Comment: This command shouldn't delete both files. A hardlink or a file is a reference to the inode of the file. A file becomes inaccessible when all these references are deleted.

Comment: mazs is right; this also means that there is no notion of an original file when you're using hard links — all hard links are equivalent.

Comment: i think there is a problem with your deletion way. just for testing , create the file and hard link in the same directory , cd into that directory and delete the hard link , and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

There does seem something strange about what you're doing.  This is on Debian testing x86_64:

```
jlquinn@cerberus:~/tmp$ mkdir dira dirb  
jlquinn@cerberus:~/tmp$ touch dira/fileA.txt  
jlquinn@cerberus:~/tmp$ ln dira/fileA.txt dirb/fileAlink.txt  
jlquinn@cerberus:~/tmp$ rm -rfv dirb/*  
removed 'dirb/fileAlink.txt'  
jlquinn@cerberus:~/tmp$ ll dira  
total 0  
-rw-r--r-- 1 jlquinn jlquinn 0 May  7 13:46 fileA.txt
```